During and after Ubuntu 24 install, WiFi works for a minute then speed drops to zero
THE BACK STORY
I've been running Ubuntu on this laptop for years with no problems.
Before installing Ubuntu 24 from a live USB, I connected to my wWiFifi network for the install process. Everything went fine for a few minutes. Then the installer started failing to download packages, and the install process eventually failed. I tried again with the same result.
Then I ran the install process without connecting the WiFi, and it completed without issue. I had to do this twice, as Grub didn't see anything after the first "successful" install. This is probably not relevant, but mentioning it just in case.
That was 2 days ago.
THE PROBLEM
The WiFi issue that broke the install process is still present on the install:

The WiFi works great for the first 50-100 MBs downloaded.
The download speed then drops to 0 (this persists until I reboot).
It maintains the WiFi network connection. It's just extremely slow to no speed at all.
It sometimes sporadically downloads a few MBs here and there.
I get mostly timeouts, but if I keep "retrying", sometimes I can load a webpage.

MY HARDWARE
I'm on an ASUS G551JM
lspci -v


04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f7980000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

LOGS
In addition to the above, I noticed that around the same time that the download speed dies, top shows that ksoftirqd starts using 100% of the cpu (this continues until I disable the WiFi).
cat /proc/interrupts

                   CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7
    ...
    18:          0   44927392          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC  18-fasteoi   i801_smbus, ath9k

After about 10 minutes, this number gets into the hundreds of millions.
The answer was eventually found by running the following systemctl command which displays ERRORS only.
sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb | less

Nov 17 09:54:46 user-G551JM kernel: ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100


This is a hardware-specific issue. The DMA failed to stop in 10 ms log entry gives it away.

DMA stands for Direct Memory Access, which is a method that allows hardware devices to transfer data directly to and from the system's memory without involving the CPU. In the context of AMD IOMMU, DMA is used to facilitate efficient data transfers while the IOMMU manages memory access and provides protection for these operations.

I disabled intel_iommu using the following steps, and now my wifi is functioning properly.
SOLUTION
STEP 1: Add intel_iommu=off to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line of the default grub config. Mine ended up looking like this:
sudo vim /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=off"

STEP 2: Apply the change:
sudo update-grub

STEP 3: Reboot, that's it!
If, for some reason, this fix doesn't work for you, you can easily revert the change. Simply remove intel_iommu=off from your /etc/default/grub file. Then, run sudo update-grub again to apply the change.
